# Launch browser into several displays

Tags: windows, browser

My final users will have PCs with up to 6 monitors, running under Windows.
I would to like to create some script that would open 6 browser windows, one for each display, each pointing to a separate URL.

- For example, the first browser window will open on display #1,
  pointing to `www.myurl1.com`
- the second browser will open on display
  #2, pointing to `www.myurl2.com`
- ...

How could I have achieve that ? Can I do that with a simple `.bat` file, or do I need to develop some .Net executable or something ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself, for those that it may help :

I've created an AIR native application than launches the Chrome browser via command line.
The command line is the following (on Windows) :

```
start chrome --kiosk --user-data-dir=user1 --windows-size=1280,960 
   --windows-position=0,0 www.mywebsite1.com
start chrome --kiosk --user-data-dir=user2 --windows-size=1280,960 
   --windows-position=1280,0 www.mywebsite2.com
...
```

The `--kiosk` option opens Chrome in fullscreen. Please note that we have to change the user name for every call, else Chrome will open all the windows in the same screen.